# create multidimensional associative array js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem with my script Javascript. I try to create a multidimensional array with dates in the key.

I would like to have something like

```
"1" : [ "2018-01-01", "2018-02-02" ]
"11" : [ "2018-01-01", "2018-02-02" ]
```

But I get something like

```
1 : [ "2018-01-01", "2018-02-02" ]
2 : ""
3 : ""
..
11 : [ "2018-01-01", "2018-02-02" ]
```

I'm doing

```
var array = [];
array[no].push(date);
```

Thanks for the future help,
MYT.

Comment: Please post your input array.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Search sparse vs dense arrays javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an **Object** rather than an **Array**.

```
var object = {};
object[no] = object[no] || [];
object[no].push(date);
```

Comment: I remember have tested it, but I made probably a mix that make it not work. Thanks it was that c: